# How to validate input for only email friendly characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, regex

I have JavaScript that validates whole email once entered:

```
function ValidateEmail(inputText)
{
    var mailformat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
    if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
    {
        alert("This is not a valid email address");
        return false;
        }
}
```

But how to check if single character is valid for email?
So I want to prevent users to enter bad email characters.
So function param would be these and should return false only if invalid character present:

```
m
my
mya
....
myaddress
....
myaddress@mail.com
```

Comment: Use `mailformat.test(inputText.value)`. See [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Why don't you use [`<input type="email" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email) and save yourself some trouble?

Comment: @Andy, I think this will only work for client side validation and wont work in server side validation.

Comment: The OP has `React` as a tag so I assume the email address is coming from there. @user11823877

Comment: @Andy, got it. It also has nodejs tag. So just wanted to confirm. also I think we need to add pattern for type="email" to validate.

Comment: @John I think this expression should work for you: ^[A-z0-9]+[@]?[A-z0-9]+[.]?[A-z0-9]+$`

Comment: What's an `email friendly character`, in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

great answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/3764369

issues follows RFC 5322
https://emailregex.com/

[w3](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php) code example:

```
function ValidateEmail(inputText)
{
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
  {
    alert("Valid email address!");
    document.form.email.focus();
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
    document.form.email.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```